# Still prompted to sign in after Google account removal

Tags: google-account, samsung-galaxy-tab-2-10.1, android-device-manager

We have a Galaxy Tab 2 that is primarily used by my wife. Until recently my Google account was on there too, I removed this on the device in Settings > Accounts. But... for some reason she still gets alerts in the notification shade to sign in to my Google account.

I can no longer see the device in Device Manager, so can't deauthorise it from there. There could be an app on there that was added using my Google account, but I can't easily find out which one it would be.

Hope someone can help?

Comment: I would suspect some Google sync operation - calendar, mail, backup, etc. could still be under your account, though the device is not. Check the settings on each of the Google Apps present on the device. Check any backup operation that may still have your Google credentials.

Comment: In addition to what wbogacz said, long pressing on the notification should allow you to view info about the app which is generating the notification. Once you've identified which app it is, try clearing its cache and data.